# Virtual Box multiple remote desktop

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop

Virtual box has a nice feature of running a remote desktop server. This allows one to connect to the virtual machine remotely. However, I cannot find how to make the connection to several desktops of the same machine.

I have several physical screens attached to the PC and, therefore, there are several desktops  available in the virtual machine. Whenever I connect to this virtual machine via the remote desktop service of virtual box, it always connects to desktop 1. While using TeamViewer, for example, I can see all the desktops.

**Question:** Is there a possibility to remotely access all the desktops of the virtual machine? I could not find any information neither in the docs nor in the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Use different Remote Desktop Server Ports in the vm's config.
Then you can connect to several instances.